# Refactoring the code and developing a clean code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have a dto as follows:

```
public class DaysDetails
{
 public bool Sun {get;set;}
 public bool Mon {get;set;}
 ...
 public bool Sat {get;set;} //All 7 days of the week
}
```

I have a method which checks if the days are checked and builds a comma separated string format . For eg: if sunday and monday are checked then the output is "0,1" (numbers corresponding to days)

```
pubic string ConstructDays(DaysDetails d)
{
 StringBuilder constructDays = new StringBuilder();
 if(d.Sun == true)
  { 
    constructDays.Append("0");
  }
 if(d.Mon == true)
 {
   constructDays.Append("1");
  }
 ..... //So on for all seven days
 string day = Convert.toString(constructDays);

 if(day != string.Empty && day[0] == ",")
   day = day.Remove(0,1);
 return day;
}
```

I need to convert this function to a more maintainable code and simplified version . What can be improved in this?

Comment: To begin with, are you permitted to change DaysDetails ? I mean, why not use a Enum with Flags ?

Comment: you can use a List instead of a CSV field

Comment: @anu : DayDetails is what I get from UI mapped fields . But yes , I am permitted to make use of any other variable derived from DayDetails and can be passed to ConstructDays function . Ultimately I need a comma separated string either from DayDetails or any custom variable passed to function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review try [codereview.se]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify your code by converting each bool to int and joining the resulting collection.

```
public class DaysDetails
{
    public bool Sun { get; set; }
    public bool Mon { get; set; }
    public bool Sat { get; set; }
}

public string ConstructDays(DaysDetails d)
{
    var week = new[]
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(d.Sat),
        Convert.ToInt32(d.Sun),
        Convert.ToInt32(d.Mon),
    };
    return string.Join(",",  week);
}
```

Or if your looking for more than just 0/1:

```
public string ConstructDays(DaysDetails d)
{
    var week = new[]
    {
        d.Sat ? 0 : -1,
        d.Sun ? 1 : -1,
        d.Mon ? 2 : -1,
        //...//
    }.Where(x => x != -1);
    return string.Join(",",  week);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the classe properties like :

```
pubic string ConstructDays(DaysDetails d)
{
 int Idx = 0;
    string days = "";
    var obj = new DaysDetails ();
    foreach (var p in obj .GetType().GetProperties())
    {   days += (bool)p.GetValue(obj ) ? (days=="" ? Idx.ToString() : ","+Idx.ToString()) : "";
        Idx++;
    }
return days
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a flag enum to store your values:

```
[Flags]
public enum Days
{
    None = 0,
    Sun = 1,  // 0
    Mon = 2,  // 1
    Tue = 4,  // 2
    Wed = 8,  // 3
    Thu = 16, // 4
    Fri = 32, // 5
    Sat = 64  // 6
}
```

You can set the selected days like this:

```
var days = Days.None;

if (some condition)
    days |= Days.Mon;

if (some other condition)
    days |= Days.Wed;

if (yet another condition)
    days |= Days.Sat;
```

And generate values based on which flags are set like so:

```
static public string ConstructDays(Days days)
{
    return string.Join(",", Enum.GetValues(typeof(Days))
                                .Cast<Days>()
                                .Where(d => days.HasFlag(d) && d != Days.None)
                                .Select(d => Math.Log((int)d, 2)));  // 1,3,6
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two things: make a separate method for converting a boolean to a int representation, and override the [ToString method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of generating a separate ConstructDays method.

```
public class DaysDetails
{
    public bool Sun {get;set;}
    public bool Mon {get;set;}
    ...
    public bool Sat {get;set;} //All 7 days of the week

    public override string ToString() {
        //formatted string
        return $"{GetNumberRepresentationOfBool(Sun)},{GetNumberRepresentationOfBool(Mon)},{GetNumberRepresentationOfBool(Sat)}"
    }
}

public int GetNumberRepresentationOfBool(bool value) {
    return value ? 1 : 0
}

//printing the value
Console.WriteLine(dayDetailsObject.ToString());
```